# Change text color of 'no file chosen'

Tags: html, css, button, input-type-file

It always creates a button where 'Choose file' is written, and beside that 'no file chosen' word is visible until I choose any file. But the text color is always black. Is it possible to change the font-color? I need to make it white.

```html
<input type="file">
```

Comment: You've a typo in your post `<input type="file">`

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
input[type="file"]{
    color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: How does this change the color of the No file chosen text?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
<label for="inputTag" class="label">
  Select Image
  <input id="inputTag" type="file" class="input" />
</label>
```

And then style it with CSS like this

```
.input {
  display: none;
}

.label{
 color: #730404;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

With this, whatever you put as the label will be your select output. So you won't have `Choose file` and `no file chosen` text. You can change the label color as you wish. You can even make the label a `CameraIcon`

Comment: How does this change the color of the No file chosen text?

Comment: Okay, I will definitely try this one also. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**I'm satisfied with this Answer:**

The best approach would be to have a custom label element with a for attribute attached to a hidden file input element. (The label's for attribute must match the file element's id in order for this to work).

```
    <label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
    Custom Upload
</label>
```

As an alternative, you could also just wrap the file input element with a label directly: (example)

```
<label class="custom-file-upload">
    <input type="file"/>
    Custom Upload
</label>
```

In terms of styling, just hide1 the input element using the attribute selector.

```
input[type="file"] {
    display: none;
}
```

Then all you need to do is style the custom label element. (example).

```
.custom-file-upload {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: How does this change the color of the No file chosen text?

Comment: Using the above steps, you can change the Default to a customized label!

Comment: You can customize the  label 
(  **.custom-file-upload** )...

Comment: Since the color cannot be changed, then we replace the default to a tag we can Customize the way we want e.g **label**